# Map.containsKey() vs Map.keySet().stream().anyMatch()

Tags: java

What do you think is more efficient: `HashMap.containsKey(key)` or `HashMap.keySet().stream().anyMatch(predicate)` ?

Thanks

Comment: Define efficient?

Comment: `Map.containsKey(key)` is more efficient, because loops are more efficient than streams.

Comment: @SterlingArcher: I can't imagine a definition for "efficient" remotely in keeping with the commonly-accepted meaning of the word where `Map.containsKey` wouldn't be the obvious answer here. :-)

Comment: @Sterling Archer, faster I mean, I think it depends

Comment: The two methods have completely different intentions. `containsKey` is intended for checking whether an object is a key within the map (shocking, I know). `anyMatch` is intended to check whether an arbitrary sequence of elements matches some condition. That condition may be an equality with an object, but it's not required to be.

Comment: @michaellaudrup, "faster" doesn't necessarily synonymous with "efficient". There may be faster implementation which is totally inefficient and is wasting a lot of, for example, system memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Map` is an interface, it does not make sense to speak about efficiency or performance without a specific implementation.

But let's take `HashMap` as one of the common implementations.

`HashMap.containsKey` is amortized O(1).

`Map.keySet().stream().anyMatch(predicate)` is O(N) as you iterate over keys. And we don't even mention all the objects created by this statement.

Comment: I meant the basic implementation, HashMap. I took a look on `containsKey()`, if we have too many keys for the same hash, it would be O(N) too

Comment: @michaellaudrup Therefore "amortized".

Comment: @michaellaudrup, HashMap cannot be considered the "basic implementation". Frequently used - maybe. But there are a lot more kinds of maps, hense the interface.

Comment: @michaellaudrup if you have "too many keys for the same hash" you have bigger problems.

Comment: I see, thank you all